# Robust way to play multiple audio files concurrently from the shell?

Tags: bash, macos, concurrency, core-audio, sox

I'm experimenting with playing audio files on a Mac (OS X 10.10.5) via several concurrent shell scripts. Each script runs in a separate Terminal session and periodically invokes an instance of `sox` (v. 14.4.2) to play an audio file. For example, one script might do this:

`sox foo.aif -t coreaudio`

while another script does this:

`sox bar.aif -t coreaudio`

The second file plays OK, but only after echoing the error message

`sox[8139:17123955] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x46407, name = 'sox'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.`

(/usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h isn't too helpful: it says that error code 1100 is defined as `BOOTSTRAP_NOT_PRIVILEGED`.)

Each subsequent invocation of `sox` throws the same error, as long as another instance is still playing. I've tried running up to 4 concurrent instances and get the same results.

Even though `sox` appears to be playing the files OK, this error message makes me nervous, since my application demands rock-solid stability (it will be playing up to 4 files concurrently 24/7/365). Also, I don't like peppering my Terminal sessions (or, after redirection of stderr, my log files) with unhelpful error messages.

Questions:

1. Can I safely ignore this error, since the sound files appear to be playing OK?
2. Might this error somehow be related to issues I'm having with other "downstream" audio applications? (For example, when I send audio from these `sox` instances to instances of [BUTT (Broadcast Using this Tool)](https://danielnoethen.de/), BUTT stops streaming and behaves as if it has lost connection with its audio source).
3. Are there any alternatives to `sox` that can play audio files from the command line in concurrent sessions without throwing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this thread... The error messages do not appear when I repeat the test on on a newer Mac running OS X 10.12.4. I can run 5 concurrent instances of `sox` or `afplay` without error.

As to part (3) of my original question... `afplay` is indeed a handy quick-n-dirty alternative to `sox` for previewing audio files from the command line (thanks, @Dave !). My situation, however, is multichannel (>8 channels) -- something `afplay` can't do but which `sox` does handily. But since I didn't mention the multichannel aspect in my question, I consider the question answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try afplay, it ships with macOS.  Just did a quick test with 5 instances and it seems to work.

`afplay path/to/file`.

Comment: What version of MacOS are you using? This doesn't solve the problem for me. I still get the error: `2017-05-18 15:25:32.647 afplay[36434:17617779] *** CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0x47407, name = 'afplay'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.`

Comment: I'm using 10.12.4.

Comment: Try it with the -d flag to see if it gives you any useful info

Comment: Thanks. Tried the -d flag, but it doesn't reveal anything useful. Maybe my problem is my older OS (10.10). I'll see if I can find a Mac with OS 10.12 to try...

Answer (score 0):

Original poster has probably found a way to do it but it may help other people:

You may mix two (or more) audio files running only one instance of sox, simply using the -m option:

```
$ sox -m file1 file2 -t alsa
```

Files must have the same sample-rate, and the `-t alsa` here  means we want to play it directly to the default ALSA sound card. You may use anything that can be an SoX output file of course. Anyway this is quite trivial, you probably know this and this is not my point.

In case you want to run two (or more) instances of SoX at the time, then you need to use the -q option. I don’t think this is obvious to everyone (it wasn’to me), hence this answer.

Consider this:

```
sox file1 -t alsa & sox file2 -t alsa &
```

It won’t play the two files. The two tasks will be started (in the background), but they will stay in the “Stopped” state. You may then run one (using the fg command), then the other one. But they won’t play together.

What you can do is:this:

```
   sox -q file1 -t alsa & sox -q file2 -t alsa &
```

Both files will start playing at the same time.

This is “simply” because without the `-q` option sox needs to write to the terminal, but there is only one terminal. If both processes were writing to the same terminal the output would be scrambled, so both processes are stopped until the user attach one to a terminal (which is a consequence of the `fg` command).